# How do I open ICEFaces Javascript log window?

Tags: javascript, icefaces

I'm using ICEFaces 1.8. I remember that once I opened a Javascript window via a key combination showing ICEFaces log (those you write using Ice.log, and obviously the runtime writes).

I forgot the default key combination and I can't  find it anywhere..............

Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.